# How to hide unnecessary files from intellij project view?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, user-experience

Given a sample gradle project with project structure as shown:

[image]

As you can see there are bunch of stuff you actually dont ever need to see in idea but you need them to exist...

I know about ignored file/folder types under `Editor/File Types` but those are affecting the libs and projects, idea will ignore them everywhere while i only need to hide few unnecessary entries in project view.

**Primary question : how do we hide them from project view?**

Also for very big projects somethimes it is easy if some related modules are shown one after another... but do not do like that alphabeticaly.

**Secondary question : is it possible to have customized order in project view?**

I'm using `Intellij 15 EAP IU-142.5047.6`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually I use the Scopes support for filtering out/in elements. 
I like this support and it can be use as the scope for other tool windows such as Hierarchy Call, and Find in path dialog. Moreover you can have many scopes and easily switch between them. The support for scratch files and version control - change sets - benefits from scopes support.

In order to create a new Scope:

1. open Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Scopes
2. Create a new scope by clicking on + icon
3. and then use include/exclude (recursively)

Kind regards

Answer (score 6):

In IntelliJ, version 2022.1.3 Ultimate Edition:

- Settings -> Editor-> File types
- select "Ignored Files and Folders" tab
- Click on the "+" sign to add the file extension to be ignored (files with this extension will not be displayed in the "Project" view).

Comment: no way to specify a folder? for example i have few root directores on project level and i'd like to ignore them, not see them at all, there are too many extensions, and some of them i cant ignore cos it might be contained in project itself

Comment: exactly like in the image you see i have gradles distro showin, like who ever needed it?

Comment: @vach You can specify the folder name as well as the filename as suggested by belgoros.