# Hide specific files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I know from [Intellij IDEA. Hide .iml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251624/intellij-idea-hide-iml-files) that I can hide from the Project Tool Window specific file extensions on all directories. However, I have unsuccessfully tried to hide specific files (e.g. mymodule/blah.tgz) without getting all tgz files to hide as well. In Settings -> Editor -> File Type, at the bottom, I have tried specifying full and relative paths (e.g. ~/projects/mymodules/blah.tgz) without luck.

How can I achieve this? Is this supported at all? I'm using IntelliJ 14 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following comment. 
[How to hide unnecessary files from intellij project view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886132/how-to-hide-unnecessary-files-from-intellij-project-view/32895308#32895308)

I usually use the scope support in Idea to  filter in/out files/folders in project tool window and other windows, i.e. Find.

I hope this helps.